# How can I cut an arbitrary cuboid into a chosen face of a mesh?

Tags: python, scripting, faces, bmesh

I am looking to cut a cuboid shape out of a mesh. I have been looking around for a lead to the solution, but everything I find is for a centered square. I am hoping there is a way to define the shape and location I want to take it from. From solutions I have seen on here that are similar, `bmesh.ops.inset_region` seemed like it may work, but I don’t see a way to call it in the way I would like to use it.

Is there a `bmesh` command that can do something like I want?
I am providing what I have thus far to show where I am at and what I am thinking:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

verts = [
    (0,0,0),
    (0,2,0),
    (2,2,0),
    (2,0,0),
    (0,0,2),
    (0,2,2),
    (2,2,2),
    (2,0,2)
]

faces = [
    (0,1,2,3),
    (7,6,5,4),
    (4,5,1,0),
    (7,4,0,3),
    (6,7,3,2),
    (5,6,2,1)
]

mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("Cube")
object = bpy.data.objects.new("Cube", mesh)

mesh.from_pydata(verts,[],faces)
mesh.update(calc_edges=True)

bpy.ops.object.add_named(linked=True,name="Cube")

bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()

bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(mesh)

'''
here I would choose face[5] (the top face) to make the change to with a bmesh.ops command
'''


bm.free()
```